# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel .Net 4.8

Tags: c#, tls1.2, .net-4.8

Currently, I am working on .net 4.8-based console application and I want to check if an URL is alive or not. For some URLs, I am getting the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error. Please suggest me how can I resolve this. This error is not generating on my local PC, only generating on the server. My server OS is 2012R2
Please note that I have already tried the below options but these didn't work.

Option 1:

```
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Option 2:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Option 3:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: You don't need (and should not) specify any options for `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`, you should let the operating system do that. But you need to apply *all* the steps from the official documentation, including applying the update and setting the registry settings. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392. Note that 2012R2 is end-of-life'd from this coming October, and will not get any more updates, so I strongly suggest you upgrade.

Comment: @Charlieface, Is there any way I can bypass this without updating OS or changing the registry?

Comment: No there isn't, and you should do these updates anyway, they are essential security updates for many other parts of the system. What is so difficult about updating the OS?